# UIWebView and Analytics / Tracking Nightmare

Tags: ios, html, uiwebview, google-analytics, metrics

I am building simple HTML5 presentations that will be served through an iPad app which pushes these local html5 files through UIWebView. As a developer, I am only limited to my own HTML5 code in each of these presentations. I have no access to the platform or the app these presentations reside in.

I have implemented Google Analytics. Doesn't work. I have implemented Localytics. Doesn't work. I have tried other numerous tracking platforms. They Don't work. The same code works when I upload my files to a web server and then visit it and click through. The same code does not work on the iPad. UIWebView is killing these Javascript libraries included for metrics/tracking.

Anyone ever use any metrics/tracking in a local HTML/HTML5 presentation that is served through an App using UIWebView? I am looking for somekind of solution. Your time is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"? I use both Google Analytics and Omniture from within a UIWebView and both work properly.

It sounds like you're tracking events, not just pageviews. That is, you're tracking when people tap on things. One thing that could be happening is the app is "trapping" those events. UIWebViews receive notifications when the apps inside them do certain things, so they can help those apps have a "native" experience. This includes things like link-handling, allowing an app to trap a Twitter intent, for instance, and send it to the actual Twitter app rather than keeping it in HTML.

It's not clear from your description whether this is the problem - but if it is, you would need to work with the app developer(s) if you wanted to keep using link tags. There's no choice - you can't stop the UIWebView from being notified, and if it does something with the event you won't get it back.

If all of this is true, try changing the elements to something other than  tags. A DIV or LI, for instance, would not trigger this behavior. You'd have to do more work in your app to simulate "link-following" workflows. Something like this:

```
$('.tappable-item').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Fire the analytics event

  // Possibly wait 250ms or so to let the event get recorded

  window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-href');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics only accepts requests from the domain you configured for the campaign. What I did is create a secret page on my domain, and in the html I put an iframe that loads that page.